# Javascript extends class

Tags: javascript, extends

What is the right/best way to extend a javascript class so Class B inherits everything from the class A (class B extends A)?

Comment: Actualy... is there some other way but b.prototype = new a;

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes. Therefore, this entire question doesn't make sense. Are you talking about Java? Or ActionScript? Those *do* have classes, but they have absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript. Or are you talking about some JavaScript library which implements class-based OO in JavaScript, like MooTools for example? In that case, the answer depends on what library you are talking about.

Comment: There is my Class object: https://github.com/reduardo7/sjsClass/blob/master/sjsclass.js

Comment: Take a look at this lightweight library that gives you exactly what you're asking for: Extending classes in javascript. As a bonus, it also adds interfaces and traits/mixins. https://github.com/haroldiedema/joii

Comment: See short synopsis of Javascript prototype chain, at Mozilla site:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Take a look at [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and [Inheritance Patterns in JavaScript](http://www.bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php).

The simplest method is probably functional inheritance but there are pros and cons.

Comment: Second link is dead.

Comment: The second link is now here: http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

Answer (score 30):

Douglas Crockford has some very good explanations of inheritance in JavaScript:

1. [prototypal inheritance](https://crockford.com/javascript/prototypal.html): the 'natural' way to do things in JavaScript
2. [classical inheritance](https://crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html): closer to what you find in most OO languages, but kind of runs against the grain of JavaScript

Comment: wow, this is so well explained by Douglas Crockford, thanks for these great links.  His patterns to create [public/privileged/private](https://crockford.com/javascript/private.html) methods is a revelation.

Answer (score 1):

```
   extend = function(destination, source) {   
          for (var property in source) {
            destination[property] = source[property];
          }
          return destination;
    };
```

[Extending JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/extending-javascript-objects-in-the-classical-inheritance-style.html#fbid=gxdrr8MOJm2)

You could also add filters into the for loop.

Comment: This is neither what OP asked nor correct "extend" - you should iterate over Object.keys or at least check for hasOwnProperty

Comment: Needs hasOwnProperty check and will overwrite methods and properties if they are the same, without the ability to call the super class method later.