# Extending non-basejs objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using ThreeJS and BaseJS. I want to extend `THREE.Object3D` into a new class. However, since it was not made with BaseJS, it does not have the function `.extend`. Is it possible to add these functions so that it is extensible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256040/javascript-extends-class

Comment: My problem is I did not create `THREE.Object3D`, I couldn't use `.extend` to create it. I looked at "Simple JavaScript Inheritance" but couldn't find my answer.

Comment: I went for `THREE.Object3D.extend = Class.extend;` and it seems to have worked. Am I doing something wrong? (using [John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/))